# NumberDecimalDigits no me funciona

Tags: c#, string, programación-funcional, numberformat

Tengo el siguiente código para que me muestre solo como máximo 2 decimales, pero no me funciona. A que se puede deber?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
var conversor = new NumberFormatInfo();
conversor.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
conversor.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
conversor.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
conversor.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;

columna.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToSingle(sacavalorbasededatos) / dias) * 30.0f, conversor);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Convert.ToString` es lo mismo que `_tipo_.ToString`. `ToString` por defecto utiliza el modificador de formato [`G`(General)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString). Si vamos a la documentación, podemos leer lo siguiente:

> La información de formato del objeto NumberFormatInfo actual afecta a la cadena de resultado. En la tabla siguiente se enumeran las propiedades de NumberFormatInfo que controlan el formato de la cadena de resultado.

```
Propiedad de NumberFormatInfo            Descripción
=============================            ===========
      NegativeSign                       Define la cadena que indica que un número es negativo.
      NumberDecimalSeparator             Define la cadena que separa los dígitos integrales de los decimales.
      PositiveSign                       Define la cadena que indica que un exponente es positivo.
```

Es decir, que con el formato por defecto que usa `Convert.ToString` ("G"), la propiedad `NumberDecimalDigits` no afecta a la conversión a cadena.

Tienes varias opciones. Una te la ha expuesto correctamente @Marc en su respuesta. Otra sería hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
columna.Text = ((Convert.ToSingle(sacavalorbasededatos) / dias) * 30.0f).ToString("N",conversor);
```

Usando esta sobrecarga de `ToString`, puedes especificar otro formato ("N") al que si afecta la propiedad `NumberDecimalDigits` del `NumberFormatInfo`.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer lo que buscas usando [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8), de la siguiente manera:

```
columna.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", (Convert.ToSingle(sacavalorbasededatos) / dias) * 30.0f);
```